# Arithmetic Logic Unit - Switching Function - Proof

Tags: assembly, cpu, logical-operators, processor, alu

I hope this is the correct section to ask. Since the ALU is part of a processor which is a part of computer, I think it's not too bad.

Given is an `n-Bit-ALU` with `OM (=operating mode)`, `control vector S=(S_0, S_1, S_2, S_3)` and `2 entrace vectors A=(A_n-1, A_n-2, ..., A_o), B=(B_n-1, B_n-2,..., B_o)`. `Extrance vector Q = (Q_n-1, Q_n-2, ..., Q_0)`.

The switching function of the ALU is:

[image]

Proof that `Q = B` if `S = 1001` and `OM = 1`

`S= 1001` means `S_0 = 1, S_1 = 0, S_2 = 0, S_3 = 1`

OM operating mode describes if the operation is arithmetic or logic. OM = 1 --> logic operation (AND, OR, NOR...) if OM = 0 its an arithmetic operation (addition, sub, mul...)

So if we put that into this term we have:

[image]

But I don't know what to do now to get `Q = B`.

I get to:

[image]

No idea how to continue or if it's correct at all.

I hope someone can help me here please I got no one else to ask that. This is no homework. It's a task from an old exam (2014) but sadly there were no solutions and now I'm trying to solve all tasks. And these ones I don't understand, I try solve as much as I can and post here like this one.

Comment: What is C_i-1? It appeared somewhat fast for my slow thinking.. also symbol "V" in this case is still logical OR, as I recall it's usage from my uni? Then (1 V ..anything ) will end as 1? I'm quite lost, sorry. Would need some explanation to recall what is what exactly.

Comment: C_i-1 the -1 confused me too here but C_i means carry. Symvol "V" means OR, yes. (1 V anything) will end as 1 I believe but not sure about that : /

Comment: But im pretty sure (1 AND anything) = anything. OR should be the opposite, so it should be right our thought.

Comment: Ok, then I get it even less, the OM is constant 1? What is then the triple `=`, I though it's some sort of equivalence, but then I end with yours `Q_i = 1`, which is no way equal to B_i obviously, thus we did prove Q != B (only for case where B is full of ones).

Comment: OM operating mode describes if the operation is arithmetic or logic. OM = 1 --> logic operation (AND, OR, NOR...) if OM = 0 its an arithmetic operation (addition, sub, mul...)

Comment: Maybe the task is complete bullsh...? I don't see a way getting this Q = B

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a theoretical ALU design and not about programming.

Comment: So where would you suggest asking this question?

Comment: Do you a source? For example, the website or book where you found this?

Comment: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3709/4qywjyna_pdf.htm
"Aufgabe 3"

Comment: By the way, why asking for source if you don't contribute anything anyway?